# select jquery onChange not working with X-editable

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jsfiddle, x-editable

In [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xameeramir/b8eb83cb/), I'm using [X-editable](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/).
In the corresponding fiddle, I'm not able to make the below code working:

```
$('#practice').on('change', function() {
  alert(this.value);
});
```

- I'm already using [anonymous function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24610538/2404470)
- I'm not using [invalid expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29739018/2404470)
- I'm using [`this`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36874771/2404470)
- I'm using [`select`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14942187/2404470)
- Console is not throwing any error as such.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What console errors are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you inspect the DOM when the editable is active (ie. the `select` is visible) you'll see that the `select` is not actually a child of the `#practice` span - it's in a sibling `span` named `.editable-container`. This is why your delegated event handler on `#practice` is not working.

That being said, if you read the [X-Editable documentation](https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html#editable) there is an event you can hook to to achieve this directly without you needing to attach your own events - `save`.

Try this:

```
$('#practice').on('save', function(e, params) {
    alert(params.newValue);
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/b8eb83cb/3/)

Comment: Oh my god, how did you inspected the DOM? Can you pehleeeeez tell me. I mean this is extreme expertise.

Comment: Depending on your browser it's right click any element > `Inspect`, or just press the F12 key :)